# можно ли в asp.net 2.0 подключить к функционалу даты/времени/календаря, например Jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

можно ли в asp.net 2.0 подключить к функционалу даты/времени/календаря, например Jquery datepicker и как это сделать? Потому что встроенный календарь asp.net 2.0 очень старый и плохой. Вот код календаря и даты и времени в данный момент.:

```
<tr>
                <td class="alignRight">
                    <asp:Label ID="StartTimeLabel" runat="server">Начало временного интервала даты регистрации (время):</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="StartTimeRegistry" CssClass="Time" runat="server" Width="80px" OnTextChanged="UpdateRegistryGridView">00:00:00</asp:TextBox>
        </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td class="alignRight">
                    <asp:Label ID="StartDateLabel" runat="server">Начало временного интервала (дата):</asp:Label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="StartDateRegistry"  runat="server" data-mask="00/00/0000" CssClass="CalendarClass" Visible ="true" Width="80px" OnTextChanged="StartDateRegistry_TextChanged" >00.00.0000</asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="StartDateRegistryLinkButton" OnClick="StartDateCalendar_Click" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                    <div style="z-index: 100; position: absolute">
                    
                        <asp:Calendar ID="StartDateRegistryCalendar" runat="server" CssClass="calendar" BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="White" OnSelectionChanged="StartDateCalendar_SelectionChanged"
                            Visible="False"  DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
            Height="200px" SelectionMode="Day" ShowGridLines="True" Width="220px" 
            OnDayRender="Calendar_DayRender">
                            </asp:Calendar>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: у меня такое чувство. чты Вы логически смешиваете серверную сторону, написанную на C#, и клиентскую сторону, на которой и может употребляться вот этот самый контрол.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery datepicker -- это библиотека на js для HTML-страничек в браузере. Js всё равно откуда у вас взялся HTML, он начинает работать на клиентской стороне и связан с бэкендом только через сгенерированный HTML.

Поэтому подключить, конечно, можно. Сперва сгенерируйте простое текстовое поле с датой (`<input type="text">`). А потом прицепите к этому полю datepicker, добавив на страницу [js-кода](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).